# SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" is missing

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

i copied a project from one computer to another. If i open the Project i get a error-message "Das angegebene SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" wurde nicht gefunden." Tanslate: "SDK ..Web not found".

I searched in another questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694411/visual-studio-2017-update-3-the-sdk-microsoft-net-sdk-web-specified-could-no). But i don't have a global.json and i don't know, where i must place it.

And i think the problem is another where. on source computer, the solution can be load. only on target computer i can't load.

Edit: I installed the latest Update of Visual Studio 2017 Community

Comment: seems like maybe you are using a later update of VS on your new machine. https://andrewlock.net/the-sdk-microsoft-net-sdk-web-specified-could-not-be-found/

Comment: I installed the latest update first.

Comment: read through the articles they are consistent with the SO post you mentioned. the original link I sent links to: https://andrewlock.net/the-net-core-2-0-preview-1-version-numbers-and-global-json/ 
I would read that one closely as well

Comment: the  Global.json file is a  VS Core attribute if your project solution file was created for/by Core originally it should be  in the same folder as your solution file: .sln

Comment: I searched for global.json file. But i don't found one. If I prove the information correctly, i should delete the file.

Comment: was the project a .net Core project originally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some different Versions of Core installed. But only the oldest one was used. The command dotnet --version shows me the problem. After deinstalling the old version, i can run my app :).

Answer (score 1):

In the VS installer, make sure you selected the workloads for cross-platform and web development so the required components are added to your VS installation.

Comment: I reinstall the VS installer, but it dosn't fix the problem.

Comment: Use "Modify" and make sure the workloads are selected

Comment: I have modify it. But it dosn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had already uninstalled some out of date SDK versions. It turns out that left a dotnet.exe with no related sdk folder at C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe. My machine like most is 64bit and newer sdks are installed at C:\Program Files\dotnet. The cmd path was preferring the older version. I renamed the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet to C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet.old (I'm not 100% sure something doesn't crop up that needs the files there so just to be safe). Everything then works.