# Project File Is Incomplete and NETCore.App 2.1 was not found on updated Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

Running into a problem I've not encountered before.

Fresh install of Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 7 enterprise.

Before updating Visual Studio I did not encounter Issue 1.

Ran update on Visual Studio to get to version 15.8

This appears to have also updated dotnet core to 2.1.4

**Issue 1**

Before upgrading to 15.8 this was not an issue.

Since I have upgrade Visual Studio i am met with the following error when trying to open [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers)

I have read the answers on a very much related question, here [Project file is incomplete. Expected imports are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432666/project-file-is-incomplete-expected-imports-are-missing) though nothing has helped.

[image]

**Issue 2**

May be related, though trying to scaffold a dbContext for EF Core and receiving this error message in the Package Manager Console.

[image]

The error message seems pretty self explanatory, except for the fact that i have the following versions installed:

[image]

I've tried removing each of the installed versions though nothing seems to get me past either of these issues.

I've tried repairing visual Studio and also the dotnet installs. Again, nothing helps.

Any idea what i have wrong? All seems to be since i upgraded to 15.8...

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please install x86 version of dotnet core SDK as well

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem - Project file is incomplete. Expected imports missing.

After installing the x86 version of the .net core sdk, Visual studio was able to open my .net core project.

Answer (score 1):

My issue is resolve by installing x86 version of dotnet core SDK