# .NetCore Projects are not loading after VS2017 update (target version 15.8.7)

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I just did an update of my vs2017 professional to verion 15.8.7 ,and after restart of vs , my .net core projects are not loading and after trying reload action i get this message :

"error  : Project file is incomplete. Expected imports are missing."

[image: error]

.Net Core Info:

[image: dotnet version]

Environment variables:

[image: EV]

Comment: i tried even file---> new ".net core console project" the results were no items showed on the file explorer area on vs but they exists on HD

Comment: I doubt it will help, but many weird problems with VS go away if you delete the (hidden) .vs folder.  Good luck.

Comment: thnx @bobwki , i ended up reinstalling VS2017 from "Administrator Windows Session", then all problems were gone, i believe the problem was some authorizations restrictions on my windows session user somehow VS wasn't capable to access .netcore .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Project file is incomplete. Expected imports are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432666/project-file-is-incomplete-expected-imports-are-missing)

Comment: Try to rename or remove global.json file.