# The Current .Net SDK does not support targeting .Net Core 2.2 Target .Net Core 2.1 or Lower

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have some projects in the preview version of .net core 2.2 preview 3.
It was working fine until i updated my VS Studio Community Edition to Version 15.9.2.
After that targeting .net core 2.2 preview is no longer possible.
When i do `dotnet --list-sdks` I get a list of the SDKs installed including 2.2.100-preview3.

[image: SDKs Installed]

After updating VS Studio, the list now only shows
[image: VS Set Target Framework]

I have followed similar questions but could not resolve the issue.
Any pointers?

Comment: What happens if you edit the csproj to target netcoreapp2.2?

Comment: That's when i get the above error

Comment: Have you reported it to visual studio?

Comment: Like I commented in the other thread (which this thread is duplicate to), make sure you subscribe to Microsoft team blogs, or you simply miss such announcements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/387549/net-22-loast-afte-upgrading-to-1592.html

seems that the latest release turns off the use of preview, 
"Use previews of the .NET Core SDK" option under menu -> Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> .NET Core

go here to turn it back on.

Comment: .Net core 2.2 is no longer in preview as per my knowledge so why do we have to enable the preview?

Comment: I have this checkbox checked but .net core 2.2 still doesn't show up.

Comment: Have the same problem... enabling this does not show up 2.2. Even more:msbuild can't target 2.2 and says .NET SDK does not support targeting Net core 2.2 while i have 2.2.3 installed

Comment: Not only is 2.2 not a preview, it doesn't make my error go away even after a restart

Comment: Another issue with these symptoms is that the 2.2.2xx SDK is not supported in VS 2017.  You will need the 2.2.1xx SDK for VS 2017.  See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55529011/1509

Comment: Thank you Daniel, your answer helped me after 2+ hours of headaches when upgrading from 2.1 to 2.2!!

Comment: The answer from @DanielPlaisted worked for me too. Once I installed SDK v 2.2.1xx, then VS2017 was able to build ok.

Comment: This has now moved to `Environment -> Preview Features`