# .net core 2.2 missing in my VS2017 installation despite being installed

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I just installed .net core 2.2 SDK, and activated the respective checkbox:

[image: .net Core Settings]
[image: Use Previews]

This is my output of `dotnet --list-sdks`:

```
1.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.505 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.602 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

But it doesn't show up in VS2017:
[image: .net versions]

When I set the target to `netcoreapp2.2` manually, I get:

```
NETSDK1045  The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.2.
```

I know there are a lot of other people having asked this question, but none of their steps helped in my case.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [SDK 2.2.**1**05](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2), the 2.2.**2**xx [SDK is for Visual Studio 2019/MS Build 16.x only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55514068/1466046).

Comment: This did the trick. That should be documented somewhere...

Comment: That worked for me as well. I was having the same issue after installing the latest version of VS2017 (15.9.11) and .Net Core 2.2 (2.2.202). Installing an older version of the .Net Core SDK (v2.2.103) worked a treat.