# How to enable ASP.Net Core 2.2 in Visual Studio 2017 Professional Edition

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

How can I activate ASP.Net Core 2.2 project creation in Visual Studio 2017 Professional edition 15.9.6.

I tried to go to `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > .NET Core` and **checked mark** the checkbox, but that does not work. Please help

[image: Enable 2.2]

[image]

Comment: Have you installed https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2 ?

Comment: There are two buttons to click 1. `.NetCore SDK` and 2. `.NetCore Runtime`, which one I need to download? Both?

Comment: You need to install .Net Core SDK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Core 2.2 Can't be Selected In Visual Studio Build Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329290/net-core-2-2-cant-be-selected-in-visual-studio-build-framework)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to install the .NET Core 2.2 SDK which you can download from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2.

It appears that you only have .NET Core 2.1 SDK installed at the moment.

Comment: I only installed Visual Studio, I am a beginner and I just got this Visual Studio from my office with license and all, and  think 2.1 was included with it. So to answer your question, I never EXPLICITLY installed EVEN 2.1. Do you mind telling me why 2.2 is not included in Visual Studio 2017 even in latest version. It is expected?

Comment: The installer probably added .NET SDK 2.1 when you installed Visual Studio with  the ".NET Core cross-platform development" option selected. As to why it doesn't automatically install newer versions, I'm not really sure. I had to install 2.2 before I could use it too. The 2.2 SDK is listed in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) as a prerequisite for upgrading a project from 2.1, which suggests it's intentional.

Comment: Sorry for these silly small questions, but there are two buttons to click 1. `.NetCore SDK` and 2. `.NetCore Runtime`, which one I need to download? Both?

Comment: You only need the SDK, since that will include the runtime anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Install the .net core 2.2 SDK. You can find it at https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

Answer (score 2):

The already provided answers were not working fine for me. Even when i was able to create new .NET Core 2.2 application, the application would not run. It was failing with IIS error.

In case you have the same issue you had to download and install **SDK for visual studio** https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your sdk is installed the correct directory location C:/Program Files/dotnet/sdk otherwise it will not be displayed in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Just for a reference, the reason net core for VS versions work, while other net core versions do not, is described here:

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3124