# .Net Core 2.2 doesn't show in the Visual Studio2017 But It works in the VS 2019

Tags: .net-core

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHY0y.png

However I could select .net core 2.2 sdk in the Visual Studio 2019 at the same machine.

Comment: Take a look here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329290/net-core-2-2-cant-be-selected-in-visual-studio-build-framework

Comment: What is the content of the **global.json** file of the project on which you cannot aim for .NET Core 2.2 ?