# upgrading entity framework project to latest netcore SDK

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I downloaded and installed the latest .NetCore SDK (2.2.203) to use in my Entity Framework with Razor pages project.  My project was created using the NetCore 2.1 SDK.

In my csproj file, I see these references.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="PagedList.Mvc" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.4.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.4.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.4.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.4.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I changeed this line:

```
 <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
```

to netcoreapp.2.2, but then I get this error:

> The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET core 2.2.

How can I upgrade my project to the lastest NetCore and Entity Framework versions?

THanks!

Comment: Do any of the answers at [.NET Core 2.2 Can't be Selected In Visual Studio Build Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53329290/1115360) help?

Comment: @AndrewMorton No I already tried upgrading to Visual Studio 2019, but I still get the same error.  I also re-installed the latest netcore SDK library, restarted my PC.

Comment: Can you *create* a .NET Core 2.2 project? That would show if the problem is with some setting in the current project or with VS.

Comment: Does `dotnet --version` properly show 2.2 version?

Comment: @Prolog it shows 2.2.203

Comment: @skyeboniwell Are you building your project from VS or CLI? If only VS, then you can execute `dotnet clean` then `dotnet build` commands and see if it works. Otherwise, try to create a new project as @andrew-morton wrote.

Comment: @Prolog that did it!  Thanks!