# Troubleshooting ASP.NET Core 2.2 SDK Installation Issue in Visual Studio 2017 After Windows Update

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I recently updated my Windows and reinstalled Visual Studio 2017. Upon opening my ASP.NET Core project, I encountered an issue where Visual Studio couldn't recognize the ASP.NET Core code. To resolve this, I installed the ASP.NET Core 2.2 Software Development Kit (SDK), but unfortunately, I haven't seen any positive changes in the behavior.

Here are the steps I've taken and the current situation:

I installed the ASP.NET Core 2.2 SDK, and the installation appears successful.
I have verified that the ASP.NET Core 2.2 SDK is present on my C: drive.
However, despite these actions, Visual Studio 2017 still doesn't seem to recognize the ASP.NET Core code in my project.

Here's the specific error or behavior I'm encountering:

[this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3EfU.jpg)

I would appreciate any guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Are there additional steps I might be missing, or is there a way to verify that Visual Studio is correctly configured to use the installed ASP.NET Core 2.2 SDK?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Core 2.2 Can't be Selected In Visual Studio Build Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329290/net-core-2-2-cant-be-selected-in-visual-studio-build-framework)

Comment: Did you restart VS after installing the asp.net core 2.2 sdk?And did you install the correct version of sdk?For 64 bit operating system,you need to install x64:https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.2.402-windows-x64-installer For 32 bit,you need to install x86:https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.2.402-windows-x86-installer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to this page https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2 and download the version 2.2.7. It works with Visual Studio 2017. For some reason you need to click through the readmes and end up here https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.2/2.2.7/2.2.7-download.md. Then half-way down the page there is a link to the 64 bit (probably what you want) and 32 bit (probably not what you want ) Windows SDK installer. This seems a bit involved but they are all Microsoft sites.  Remember to restart Visual Studio after installing.

In general, you can always find what you need to download by going to dot.net (clever, no?) and following the thread of information there.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Open visual studio installer and goto ASP.NET Web Development and check SDK core 2.2 for automatically install ASP .NET Core 2.2.
If you need to install manually than [Click](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.2.7-windows-x64-asp.net-core-runtime-installer) for ASP .NET Core Runtime and [Click](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.2.402-windows-x64-installer) for ASP .NET Core SDK.