# Show 3.0 Framework in TargetFramework on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I opened a .net core mvc project in Visual Studio 2017 and I can run it. The projects load in the studio as well as it can run it just fine. However if I go to properties of any project and I look at Target framework, it is blank. When I click the dropdown I only see 1.0, 1.1, 2.0 and 2.1. There is no option for 2.2 or 3.0. I know I have it all properly installed because when I use VS 2019 these options show. I would also like them to show in 3.0.

I have gone to Options of Visual studio and enabled "Use Previews of the .NET Core SDK". I have Restarted Visual Studio several times, even my entire PC to make sure. However, it still does not show.

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: I think it's only supported in VS 2019.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Ok, am I fine to use 2017 for development or there are other things that will impact me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0

.NET Core 3.0 and above is exclusively available for VS2019. If you cannot upgrade to VS2019, you might use the SDK with tools like VSCode.

You cannot use VS2017, as it won't support things like C# 8.

You didn't see 2.2 due to another issue, [.NET Core 2.2 Can't be Selected In Visual Studio Build Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329290/net-core-2-2-cant-be-selected-in-visual-studio-build-framework/53339066#53339066)