# Visual Studio 2017 problem with .net core projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

I have a big problem with **vs 2017**. When vs2017 was open, suddenly unload my .net core project (presentaion layer, specially nop.web for nopCommerce 4.2).
I really tired for to much installing and unistalling sdks and vs2017.
I update vs2017, uninstall sdk and reinstall sdk (I know 2.2.2nn is not support so I install SDK 2.2.110).
It also create empty solution when I try to create new web (.net core) project. In fact it has create but doesn't display in vs2017. This problem is persists with .net core 2.1.
Nuget doesn't open in project, and also in error list I have this **Error**: *The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2*.
**But every things is ok in vs2019**

Comment: You'll want to read this: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3124 not all core's are created equally.  Do you need VS2017?  Try Rider as an alternative.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core 2.2 Can't be Selected In Visual Studio Build Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329290/net-core-2-2-cant-be-selected-in-visual-studio-build-framework)

Comment: What's the target framework of your project? You cannot work on netcoreapp2.2 now, as .NET Core 2.2 is end-of-life.

Comment: Have you also installed the x86 version of the sdk? had a problem with 2.1 in V2019 and had to explicitly install the x86 version. Try changing your project to x64 architecture to check if the problem still persists

Comment: vs2017 and 2019 use different versions for .net core SDKs (VS2019: 2.2.207 and for VS2017 2.2.110). So maybe if you use VS2017 it tries to use the version from VS2019

Comment: Hello everybody , as I mentioned in question I use true version for vs2017 (sdk 2.2.110),
can anyone help me? I sepend 2 days for this problem but there is still no solution.