# Console App (.NET Framework) is not listed for creating a new project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console-application

I've started new to C# and I wanted to setup Visual Studio 2019.
These are the downloads I have done [image]

But to create a new project the console app is not showing up.

[image]
[image]

Here are all the individual components installed

[image]

Comment: What happens if you search for "Console"?

Comment: Also, I **strongly** recommend this extension to everyone using VS2019: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=softworkz.SwitchProjectDialog

Comment: It seems that you only have .NET Core/ .NET 5 project in the templates. Check if any .NET Framework has been installed under `Individual Components`.

Comment: @Dai nothing happens when I search for console either.

Comment: @KyleWang Yes I have all the .NET Framework installed in the individual components.

Comment: Sometimes the Keyboard Layout you choose, "C# Keyboard", "Project Manager Keyboard" settings can affect what projects you can see. Can you reset your keyboard settings to Default? Let me know if that solves it.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I tried it but no luck. The way I did it was by resetting the import and export settings through the tools drop down list.

Comment: @RohitKrishnan Check whether you can create it with command `dotnet new console -o myApp`, or repair the VS.

Comment: @RohitKrishnan lets try via the command line and get you a .Net Core Console project. **C:\>dotnet new console**

Comment: @JeremyThompson the command line worked and a project exists. But on opening it with Visual Studio it states that `These projects are either not supported or need project behavior impacting modifications to open in this version of Visual Studio.` On pressing OK in that dialogue box VS stopped responding.

Comment: @RohitKrishnan Sounds like your VS install and/or entire computer is broken :)

Comment: @RohitKrishnan can you check you're using the right version, ie you're opening Visual Studio and NOT SSDT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50145615/495455

Comment: @JeremyThompson it is the normal version - community 2019 and not the SSTD. I did change the location of the program files directory in the windows registry editor a few times (From C:\ to E:\). I did revert it, but maybe its the reason its not working.

Comment: @Dai I am thinking of resetting the windows install drive. Maybe it would fix the issue.