# Visual Studio 2019 does not display .NET Core 2.2 in Target Framework dropdown

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-2.2

This is not a duplicate of [Visual Studio does not display .NET Core 2.2 in Target Framework dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088559/visual-studio-does-not-display-net-core-2-2-in-target-framework-dropdown/55535131#55535131) because this question is about Visual Studio 2019.

I **just installed Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.0.1**

I **have also installed .NET Core 2.2 SDKs**..., as shown below:

[image: Installed .NET SDKs]

However when I open my project, **Visual Studio 2019 still does not show .NET Core 2.2 in Target Framework**.

[image]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Meh... this is embarassing... I actually have `global.json` in my project root folder that specifies sdk version 2.1.

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.1.401"
  }
}
```

**Deleting this global.json file** and restarting visual studio solves my issue.