# How to enable .NET Core 3 preview SDK in VS2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, blazor

I wanted to try out Blazor. I've installed .NET Core 3.0 preview 5 SDK, Blazor VS extension to enable project templates. I can create Blazor project, but I can't run it - I constantly get this notification.
[image]

In some tutorials I see that there should be a checkbox in VS options - to enable using of preview SDKs.

But it's not there in VS2019! Version is 16.1.1

[image]

Comment: Try searching for "preview" in the options dialog.  I think they moved it around.

Comment: Pavel, are you using the preview version of Visual Studio 2019? If you're not then you should install it. Preview is recommended for Blazor development. Also if you're using Preview this option is on by default.

Answer (score 23):

Thanks to @Kirk Woll. They moved this checkbox indeed.
[image]

Comment: I have checked that option and I have installed .net core 3.0.100-previes9-014004 . but when I create a new web Asp.Net core project in VS 2019 I have not .net core 3 to select.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the preview channel for vs 2019 then it is on by default:
[image]