# Visual Studio 2022 is unable to start application on docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

Visual studio 2022 is unable to start a ASP.NET Core project on docker, here is what I did:

- Started VS 2022
- Created a new project based on template "ASP.NET Core Web App"
- On the template config, I had defined dotnet 6 and "Enable Docker" to true (Linux, I'm using Win 11 WSL)
- I have waited the container tools of vs to finish and then, hitted F5 to start the application on docker
- The error `Unable to resolve dotnet core version` puped:
  [image]

If I try to browse the URL on browser, I got ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Does the VS2022 template needs some modifications to work? Any help?

What I tried:

- Troubleshooting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/troubleshooting-docker-errors?view=vs-2022
- Reinstall VS2022

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also found this today.
For me the solution was to edit my PATH environment variable, re-ordering it so that the 64-bit version of dotnet executable's folder was *above* the 32-bit one, and then restart VS.

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\` needs to be before `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\`

My understanding is that the first match is used, and the dotnet sdks are not reachable from the alternative architecture.
A symptom of the problem is that calling `dotnet --list-sdks` returns nothing.
By swapping the paths as above, my list command was returning stuff again, (and I could run apps!)

Comment: It worked :) Tku.
More info about the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63746838/net-sdks-not-installing-correctly