# dotnet build stopped working after VS 2022 upgrade

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

I upgraded Visual Studio Community to the final release, and it stopped working. Specifically, I *could* generate a new project, but when I try to load it, it gave me an error

> Critical  Project 'SdkTest' load failed|   [MSB4236] The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.  ...\SdkTest.csproj

Even though build and run worked fine

I ran "repair" on VS2022, and it seems to be working now *from Visual Studio*. However, `dotnet --info` doesn't show **any** SDKs; only runtime; and `dotnet build` or `dotnet new` give an error:

```
C:\Code>dotnet new console -o myapp
Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
Possible reasons for this include:
   * You intended to execute a .NET program:
     The application 'new' does not exist.
   * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
     It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
     Install a .NET SDK from:
       https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

I even reinstalled .NET 6 and I see it in the list of applications (along with older SDKs). I checked the path, and I see everything that I expect to see:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\
C:\Program Files\dotnet\
C:\Users\me\.dotnet\tools
```

I am running Windows 11.

Comment: `Program files` should be before `Program files (x86)`, it's known bug. [Fix](https://github.com/dotnet/installer/issues/12616#issuecomment-965401018)

Comment: @JL0PD - do you want to put it as answer? I'll happily accept. I was googling with all kind of search words - and never stumbled onto that github issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's [known bug](https://github.com/dotnet/installer/issues/12616) in VS2022 installation.

Problem is that `dotnet` you access is located inside `Program Files(x86)/dotnet`, but all sdk's are located in `Program Files/dotnet`. You simply need to edit `PATH` environment variable so `Program Files/dotnet` goes before `Program Files(x86)/dotnet`. If you don't see `Program Files(x86)/dotnet` in user environment variable (which is likely to happen) then edit system environment variable (located below)

Example with screenshots: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44272417/10339675

Comment: Incidentally, while I was waiting for this answer - I downloaded and installed "dotnet-install scripts" which is generally used for CI servers. It installed another `dotnet` into `AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\` and added it to the PATH first. This also made it work. Obviously, your answer is better approach - and it explains why I had a problem I was having. Thank you

Comment: Also, a good explanation from Microsoft here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63746838/net-sdks-not-installing-correctly

Answer (score 0):

edit **Path** environment variables, and in the editing window **move up** "ProgramFiles/dotnet"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer is a duplicate of the one from @JL0PD