# .NET SDK's Not Installing Correctly by Visual Studio Installer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dotnet-sdk, visual-studio-installer

I am getting an issue with installing the .NET SDK using Visual Studio Installer.

In the list I chose the .NET 5, .NET Core 3.1 and .NET Core 2.1 SDKs and installed them, but when I use `dotnet --info`, I only see .NET 7 installed with Visual Studio 2022.

[image: result of dotnet --info]

Here you can see my Visual Studio vs JetBrains Rider (rider can't see SDK like CMD)

[image: visual studio create project screenshot]

[image: jb rider create project screenshot]

I tried to reinstall the SDKs in Visual Studio Installer but it does not have any effect.

I checked the dotnet folder in C:/ProgramFiles/dotnet and there is only .NET 7 SDK in it.

I checked my environment variables and PATH for x64 located above x86.

Comment: Why do you expect it to support a version out of support?

Comment: You could try installing the SDK directly by downloading it from Microsoft. Just google for "net sdk" and select your desired version. Please keep in mind, that versions prior to Net 5.0 are out of support.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see what you have installed try out these commands as well

```
dotnet --list-sdks
dotnet --list-runtimes
```

In my case Visual Studio doesn't need all of the different sdks it only needs the runtimes. Rider probably has to have the appropriate sdks.

Here is my output of these commands:
[image]

If you have only the runtimes, you will need to install the sdks manually.
For that you can get instructions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63752429/15439848

**I think you have only the runtimes installed. As they are the only thing listed in the visual studio installer along with a .NET general SDK.**