.NET extension not installing in Visual Studio Code
I installed the C#, .NET and .NET tools because I want to program in C# in Visual Studio Code, but I'm still getting errors. Could someone please explain me what is needed to launch C# in Visual Studio Code?
The project is still not opening even after I installed all the necessary extensions, such as C#, C++, and.Net tools in Visual Studio Code.

Error :
No installed .NET SDK was found on the computer. If it is installed, make sure it can be found through the PATH environment variable. C# Dev Kit does not work without a supported version of SDK. After installing the SDK, you need restart the VS Code session, or the computer.


Make sure you have installed .net 9 sdk(runtime and sdk are two different things). If you have already installed that still facing issue. Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63746838/net-sdks-not-installing-correctly.
